# How to implement and modify policies for Role-based access control on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, selinux, rbac

Selinux is currently installed on the machine but there's no simple way to enable and modify RBAC for users. Seedit is available for Fedora and CentOS but it is not working on Ubuntu distros.

Are there any other RBAC solutions that are supported on Ubuntu/Debian with tools like Seedit to modify the policies. SEAdmin does not work in Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 0):

[AppArmor](https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/wikis/home) is the most commonly used way to implement RBAC on Ubuntu.

Ubuntu has had AppArmor since version 7.04, and it has been turned on by default since 7.10.

Reading the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) and the [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apparmor.html.en) should help you get up and running.